# Applying TaskContinuationOptions to a "step" rather than the entire chain

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

Given the following code:

```
// TCO = TaskContinuationOptions
FirstAsyncMethod()
    .ContinueWith(t => SecondAsyncMethod(t.Result), TCO.OnlyOnRanToCompletion)
    .ContinueWith(t => HandleErrors(t));
```

If I execute it as is and `FirstAsyncMethod` throws an exception, `HandleErrors` is never called because the `TaskContinuationOptions` on `SecondAsyncMethod` stops the entire chain.

If, on the other hand, I remove the `TaskContinuationOptions` on `SecondAsyncMethod`, accessing `Task.Result` causes an `AggregateException` to thrown *as an InnerException of the orginal AggregateException*. In my actual code, this produces a ridiculous hierarchy that needs to be unwrapped.

I don't capture (ie. chain) the result of `ContinueWith`, `HandleErrors` gets called before `SecondAsyncMethod` which is obviously an issue.

Is there a way to apply `TaskContinuationOptions` to a `ContinueWith` so that it only potentially skips that step, and not any subsequent steps?

Comment: Have you considered using `Handle()` or `Flatten()` to get rid of the “ridiculous hierarchy”?

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't spotted `Flatten` as I was looking for `Unwrap`. At least I can remove my extension method :)

Comment: @RichardSzalay what did you end up doing to resolve this?  I'm faced with the exact same thing. It's looking like I might have to get rid of the "OnlyOnRanToCompletion" option and insert logic into the first ContinueWith block to skip the "SecondAsyncmethod" if an error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this by adding my HandleErrors to ALL the tasks in the chain but making them conditional on the parent task faulting.

```
Task task1 = new Task(FirstAsyncMethod());
Task task2 = task1.ContinueWith(t => SecondAsyncMethod(t.Result), TCO.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);


task1.ContinueWith(t => HandleErrors(t), TCO.OnlyOnFaulted);
task2.ContinueWith(t => HandleErrors(t), TCO.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Comment: Your `ContinueWith` on `task2` will never trigger, since task2 uses `OnlyOnRanToCompletion`

Comment: It will if the fault is in task2 and not in task1.  i.e. task1 completed fine, but then task2 blew up.  By adding the error handling task to both of your steps it doesn't matter where things break your error handling will still be called.

Comment: Or are you trying to chain so that if task1 faults, you run some handling, but then call task2 anyway?